# Spring boot Cache Abstraction custom implementation

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, hazelcast

I have a use case, where I need to handle bulk gets and single queries in a spring boot application.
Lately I realized that this can't be done with @Cacheable annotations as there partial miss scenarios can't be handled.

Is there any way I can directly access hazel cast cache instance and build a wrapper on top of that?

With this cache will be same but based on use case I can add @Cacheable or call custom implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a handle on the `CacheManager`, and then access the desired `Cache` objects like that:

```
@Bean
public CommandLineRunner run(CacheManager mgr) {
    return args -> {
        Cache cache = mgr.getCache("foo");
        // do something with cache
    };
}
```

Note the `CommandLineRunner` is just an example, but it shows how you can get a handle on the `CacheManager`, get the relevant `Cache` out of it, and inject it into your own bean.

Comment: And with this, it will still be managed by hazelcast? like TTL and other aspects of it?
Also in that case it will have to be ensured that its initialised first by hazelcast!

Comment: Also will the sequence of beans getting initialised matter in this case now as one might overwrite ttl. and other information?

Comment: _spring-cache_ is just an abstraction over a cache implementation. If you make sure to have `hazelcast-spring` on the classpath, Hazelcast will be chosen as the implementation, and you can configure it however you want. If you want control over the initialization sequence _e.g._ bean `X` before bean `Y`, you should pass `X` as an argument to the method that return `Y`. In the code above, Spring guarantees the `CacheManager` is instantiated before calling the `run()` method.

Comment: I am new to this. So can you just help me with one small doubt.


Say when i create a component which is a wrapper on top of cache instance which i get with cache manager and also there is one configuration which sets up hazel cast config.
So will the sequence of initialisation of both matter in such a scenario? Like if cache initialised first then ttl goes off or reverse?